# Flutter FFmpeg error option not found when using filter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I am very new to flutter and trying to use FFmpeg.
I want to use this filter

```
ffmpeg '-i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,avgblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart derpdogblur.mp4'
```

but it's not working when I am passing it as an argument.

My fluter code is this.

```dart
return _ffmpeg.renderHelper(args: [

      '-i $src -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=200:200:60:30,avgblur=10[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=60:30[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart $output' 
], onStats: onStats, onError: onError, onAbort: onAbort);
```

But this filter is not working I am getting the option not found error.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893030/merging-audio-file-with-video-file-in-flutter/69893336#69893336

Comment: something wrong with executing commands. no need to add "ffmpeg" for executing the command.

Comment: I have tried without ffmpeg and everything in a single quote @RohitChaurasiya